# Coloured terminal output & logging

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, makefile

I use `tput setaf [colornum] && echo [text] && tput sgr0` in a Makefile to highlight some parts of the output, which is nice to find stuff in the output quicker. My problem is that when I want to log the output, for example using `make > my_log.txt`, the file has all these control characters in front of the lines that were previously colored. Is there an easy way to have both - formatted output in the terminal as well as the ability to store it as a log? I'd prefer a solution where stdout remains loggable instead of handling the logfile internally in the script / makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test whether stdout is a terminal, before you print your magical characters.  If it's not a terminal you shouldn't print them.  You can test this with `[ -t 1 ]` (1 is the file descriptor of stdout).  So:

```
[ -t 1 ] && tput setaf [colornum]; echo [text]; [ -t 1 ] && tput sgr0; true
```

*EDIT*

I should add one thing: starting with GNU make 4.1, you can also test the make variable `MAKE_TERMOUT` and if it's set then you should assume you are writing to a terminal, even if `-t` says no.  This is because these versions of make support a new feature, `--output-sync`, which ensures that output from parallel jobs is not intermixed even during parallel builds.  In order to do this, though, make has to capture the output temporarily then display it in a serial manner which means that to shell processes it never looks like stdout is a terminal.  If you're using that version of GNU make you can use something like:

```
$(if $(MAKE_TERMOUT),tput setaf [colornum];) echo [text] $(if $(MAKE_TERMOUT),; tput sgr0)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! So I guess `-t` checks for the file descriptor that you're currently outputting to? That's very useful to know.

Comment: No.  `-t` checks the descriptor that you give it.  Above I gave it the descriptor `1`, which, as I mentioned in my answer, is the descriptor for stdout.  You could use `2` for stderr, or `0` for stdin if you wanted to, or any other number as well if you happened to know they were valid.

Comment: I see, so when stdout is redirected to a file, the 'stdout file' with describtor 1 is not seen as 'open' in bash. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: No.  It is still open (otherwise the output would be lost: it wouldn't go anywhere).  But, it's not connected to a terminal device.  That's what the `-t` test option checks for.